# How do view controllers work in the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, model-view-controller

I have just started developing iPhone applications and I am very confused by how the "view controller" aspect of the user interface works.

I did the "Your First iPhone Application" tutorial on the Dev Center. It has you set up your own view controller class and then initialize it using initWithNibName. So it seems that nib files contain view controllers. But it's also possible to have a nib file that just has a view, not a view controller. For example if you set up a TabBarController and then navigate to any tab other than the first one, there will be a gray box that says "view" and if you double click that you get to set up a view to go in that tab (but it's just a view, not a view controller, am I right?) So are views subclasses of view controllers or vice versa?

Another thing I am having trouble understanding is nested view controllers. The way I understand that you use a view controller (at least from the tutorial) is that you create your own custom view controller (or is it actually a view controller? In the tutorial I don't see where myViewController is actually declared to extend UIViewController) that has all the delegate methods in it, and then use initWithNibName to load the existing view controller into the custom view controller. (Right so far?) So suppose I create a nib file with a TabBarController at the root, and of course each tab will have a root view controller. So then I loadWithNibName the file and stick it in my own root view controller. Now how do I get access to all the "internal" view controllers so that I can assign delegate methods to them? Or is the recommended option to make the root view controller the delegate for both its own view and the views of all the subsidiary view controllers?

Here's another example. I am planning to have a TabBarController where for some of the tabs,  the view controller for that tab will be a NavigationController. The way I understand navigation controllers is that you have to programmatically push a view on top of the stack when you want to drill down in the hierarchy. Suppose the view I pushed on is a view I originally created in Interface Builder (and loaded in using initWithNibName.) But of course the space to display the view is smaller than the space available for the view when I created it (because when I created it it was on a blank slate, while when I display it there's a navigation bar and a tab bar using up some of the screen.) So do the view controllers automatically resize the view to compensate? (IIRC, part of the documentation did mention auto-resizing somehow, but it seems like since the aspect ratio changes, scaling to the right size would leave the text looking "squashed".)

Finally is there some tutorial or explanation somewhere that explains clearly how the view controllers work? That also might help me answer my questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Docs on view controllers and learning related stuff

(1) [Apple's `UIViewController` reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Short and sweet (relatively).

(2) [View Controller Programming Guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).  More wordy.

(3) Not view controller specific, but still: [Cocoa Dev Central](http://cocoadevcentral.com/).  Education with pretty pictures.

---

#### Nested View Controllers

The fact is that there are some key points that are a tad glossed over in the introductory docs.  And I think a lot of the confusion arises from using the tab bar controller and navigation controller in particular.

For example:

> You should not use view controllers to manage views that fill only a part of their window—that is, only part of the area defined by the application content rectangle. If you want to have an interface composed of several smaller views, embed them all in a single root view and manage that view with your view controller.

*-`UIViewController` class reference*

So, that certainly makes it sound like you should never nest view controllers, right?  Well, from my experience, what they *meant* to say was something more like *never nest view controllers, except maybe in a tab bar controller, or in a navigation controller, or in a navigation controller in a tab bar controller.  But other than that, never nest view controllers.*

---

#### View resizing

Another good question you raise: Is the coder responsible for sizing the view, or is that done by a view controller?  And the usual answer is: yes, the coder is responsible for all layout and exact sizing of view elements -- *except* when that view is the first one added to a tab bar or navigation controller -- they tend to be somewhat aggressive about sizing your views for you.  There are more details to know - things like autoresizing your view if the orientation changes - but this is a good rule of thumb to start with.

---

#### Views vs view controllers (and models)

Neither views nor view controllers are subclasses of each other.  They're independent dudes.  Generally, a view controller is more in charge, and tells the view what data to display, or where to position itself, etc.  Views don't really tell controllers what do to, except perhaps to inform them of a user action, such as a `UIButton` calling a method in its controller when it gets pushed.

Here's a quick analogy to help understand the whole MVC model.  Imagine you're building the UI for a car.  You need to build a dashboard to display information to the driver - this is the view.  You need sensors to know how fast it's going, how much gas you have, and what radio station is on - this data and direct data-handling stuff are like model objects.  Finally, you need a system which knows when to turn on the low-on-gas light, or to turn off your turn signal when you turn the wheel far enough, and all the logic like that - this is the controller component.

---

#### Other stuff

A nib file is mostly a way to save view-related data that would make for ugly code.  You can think of them logically as freeze-dried class instances, ready to use.  For example, positioning a grid of 20 buttons that will be the UI for a calculator; a bunch of pixel coordinates makes for boring code, and is a lot easier to work with in interface builder.  It can also accommodate view controllers because that code is also occasionally very boilerplate - such as when you need a standard, everyday tab bar controller.

About which view controllers control which views: Again, the tab bar and navigation controllers are kind of special cases, as they can act as containers for other view controllers.  By default, you think of having just one view controller in charge of the full screen at a time, and in that case, there's no question that this one view controller is handling any delegated calls back from your view or other elements.  If you *do* have some container view controllers, then it still makes sense for the most-specific view controller (the most nested one) to be doing all the dirty work, at least for the views which are not controlled by the container controllers (i.e. anything not the tab bar / navigation bar).  This is because the container view controllers aren't usually considered as knowing about what they contain, and this agnosticism gives us better decoupled, and more maintainable code.

And, yes, in this context a view controller is always meant to be a subclass of `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

View controllers are simply that - objects that handle control of a view.

A XIB files doesn't "contain" a view controller.  Instead it normally tells a XIB, what view controller it will be wired up to eventually - that's what the initWithNib call is doing, creating a view controller, getting the view out of the xib, and then attaching the view controller to where the XIB says it should connect to parts of the view.

There are nested view controllers technically when you use a navigation controller or tab bar, but your own view controller basically gets called as if it were the top level because those containers understand they will be holding other view controllers.

As for resizing - it's not a pixel resize, it's a container resize.  The view controller resizes the master view it's hooked up to, then the auto-resizing behavior for any elements that view holds determines how they are resized - some things like lables might shift around, but by default do not shrink.  If you click on the Ruler tab in IB you can see the current autoresize behavior for any object in a view - the center lines with arrows at both ends tell you if an object will allow resizing, and in which directions.  The lines on the outside of the square tell you what side(s) the object will "stick" to, meaning the object will keep the same distance from those edges no matter how the container holding it resizes.

I'm not sure what the best book for IB is, but you probably cannot go wrong with a good fundamental Cocoa book which should explain autoresize behaviors.